# "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "range" at 'data[0]'" when using Google Sheet APIv4 batchUpdate() in Python

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I followed the reference code in the guide -- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values. However, I am getting the error "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "range" at 'data[0]': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list" when I call batchUpdate().

Any suggestion on what may be wrong and how to fix it?

```
# Preparing data to be written back to sheet
data = [
    {
        'range': range_name,
        'values': values
    },
]

body = {
    'valueInputOption': "USER_ENTERED",
    'data': data,
}

request = service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, body=body)
response = request.execute()
```

content of "body" =

```
{'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED',
 'data': [{'range': ['!B251:I251', '!B252:I252', '!B254:I254', '!B256:I256'],
   'values': "[['2020-06-04', 2, '123456789098765421abcdefg', '', 'test1', 1, None, 1], ['2020-06-04', 1, '123456789098765421abcdefg', '', 'test2', -1, None, 1], ['2020-06-04', 2, '123456789098765421abcdefg', '', 'test1', 3, None, 1], ['2020-06-04', 1, '123456789098765421abcdefg', '', 'test9', 4, None, 1]]"}]}
```

[myCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94e3o.png)

From the guide,

```
values = [
    [
        # Cell values ...
    ],
    # Additional rows
]
data = [
    {
        'range': range_name,
        'values': values
    },
    # Additional ranges to update ...
]
body = {
    'valueInputOption': value_input_option,
    'data': data
}
result = service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=body).execute()
print('{0} cells updated.'.format(result.get('totalUpdatedCells')))
```

Yet, the error msg seems to indicate the param 'range' is not known?

Comment: Please include the code and small sample data directly in the question, see here how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Several things:

- You are trying to pass to `range` and array of ranges while the method expects a single range per item, the corect request would be:

```
 "data": [
    {
      "range1": "",
      "values1": []
    },
    {
      "range2": "",
      "values2": []
    }
  ]
```

- You use `None` for an empty value - instead you need to leave an empty space between commas: `1,2, ,4` (or wrap `None` in `"` quotes if you want to pass it as a string
- A JSON object expects double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'` for vlaues and range notations

I recommend you to test your request syntax with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) feature before implementing into Python.